# Spring boot cassandra Failed to load ApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data-jpa

I am integrating spring boot, spring data jpa and cassandra. but getting below error. please help me to resolve this.

```
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.lo
 adContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117) ~[spring-test-
 5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
... 26 common frames omitted
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: @ConditionalOnMissingBean did 
 not specify a bean using type, name or annotation and the attempt to deduce the bean's type failed
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanSearchSpec.validate(OnBeanCondition.java:389) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.M3.jar:2.0.0.M3]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanSearchSpec.<init>(OnBeanCondition.java:379) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.M3.jar:2.0.0.M3]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:113) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.M3.jar:2.0.0.M3]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.M3.jar:2.0.0.M3]
... 42 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanTypeDeductionException: Failed to deduce bean type for org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.cassandra.CassandraDataAutoConfiguration.cassandraMapping
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanSearchSpec.addDeducedBeanTypeForBeanMethod(OnBeanCondition.java:442) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.M3.jar:2.0.0.M3]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanSearchSpec.addDeducedBeanType(OnBeanCondition.java:426) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.M3.jar:2.0.0.M3]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanSearchSpec.<init>(OnBeanCondition.java:373) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.M3.jar:2.0.0.M3]
... 44 common frames omitted
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.CassandraMappingContext
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:255) ~[spring-core-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanSearchSpec.addDeducedBeanTypeForBeanMethod(OnBeanCondition.java:436) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.M3.jar:2.0.0.M3]
... 46 common frames omitted

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 28.532 sec 
<<< FAILURE! - in com.trendset.ecom.EcomApplicationTests
contextLoads(com.trendset.ecom.EcomApplicationTests)  Time elapsed: 0.064 
sec  <<< ERROR!
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.cassandra.CassandraDataAutoConfiguration.cassandraMapping
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: @ConditionalOnMissingBean did not specify a bean using type, name or annotation and the attempt to deduce the bean's type failed
 Caused by: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanTypeDeductionException: Failed to deduce bean type for org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.cassandra.CassandraDataAutoConfiguration.cassandraMapping
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.CassandraMappingContext
```

Below are the spring, cassandra dependencies i am using.

```
   spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-1.5.5
   spring-boot-starter-web
   cassandra-driver-mapping(com.datastax.cassandra)
   spring-data-cassandra-1.0.0.RELEASE
  cassandra-driver-extras(com.datastax.cassandra)
```

Cassandra config file

```
 @Configuration
 @PropertySource(value = { "classpath:cassandra.properties" })
 @EnableCassandraRepositories(basePackages = { "com.test.stu.cassandra" })
 public class CassandraConfig {
  private static final Logger LOG = 
 LoggerFactory.getLogger(CassandraConfig.class);

  @Autowired
  private Environment env;

  @Bean
  public CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster() {

    CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster = new CassandraClusterFactoryBean();
    cluster.setContactPoints(env.getProperty("cassandra.contactpoints"));
    cluster.setPort(Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("cassandra.port")));

    return cluster;
  }

  @Bean
  public CassandraMappingContext mappingContext() {
    return new BasicCassandraMappingContext();
  }

  @Bean
  public CassandraConverter converter() {
    return new MappingCassandraConverter(mappingContext());
  }

  @Bean
  public CassandraSessionFactoryBean session() throws Exception {

    CassandraSessionFactoryBean session = new CassandraSessionFactoryBean();
    session.setCluster(cluster().getObject());
    session.setKeyspaceName(env.getProperty("cassandra.keyspace"));
    session.setConverter(converter());
    session.setSchemaAction(SchemaAction.NONE);

    return session;
  }

  @Bean
  public CassandraOperations cassandraTemplate() throws Exception {
    return new CassandraTemplate(session().getObject());
  }
 }
```

somebody please let me know what else I need to do to integrate cassandra with spring-data jpa and spring boot.

Thanks in advance